# Reselect item on Select2 multi-value select list

Tags: oracle-apex

I use plugin Select2 on Apex.

I have scenario like this:

1. I have three tables: ROOM, MASTER_STUDENT and MAP_STUDENT_ROOM
2. One ROOM can have many STUDENT
3. User can select more than one student(with Select2 from MASTER_STUDENT) when create ROOM
4. When user edit ROOM, previously selected student show in Select2 item(selected item by MAP_STUDENT_ROOM), so user can remove or add more Student

How to achieve point number 4, item Select2 list of values is MASTER_STUDENT but with default selected by MAP_STUDENT_ROOM?

I found this [documentation](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items), but i dont know how to apply it.

Comment: What version of APEX are you using? If you go to "Source" for the item, do you see a setting named "Form Region"? If so, what is it set to?

Comment: Also, how are you processing the page on load and on submit? Are you using automated row processing or manual PL/SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether you're using the Select2 plug-in or the built-in Popup LOV, the issue will be the same. You have a form on ROOM, that's trying to take into account an item that isn't part of the ROOM table (its values are stored in MAP_STUDENT_ROOM). The trick is to populate the item correctly during page load so that the item can correctly display the currently assigned students.

How is the item's Source configured? If it's not, set **Type** to **SQL Query (return colon separated value)**. Assuming you have a primary key item on the page for the room (e.g. P1_ID), enter a query like the following:

```
select student_id
from MAP_STUDENT_ROOM
where room_id = :P1_ID
```

Then set **Used** to **Always, replacing any existing value in session state**.

This should get the item to display correctly when the page loads. However, you'll still have to figure out how to map the values back to the MAP_STUDENT_ROOM table correctly when the page is submitted. You'll need to add some logic that first deletes rows from the room (P1_ID) that are not in the selection (e.g. P1_ASSIGNED_STUDENTS). You can use [APEX_STRING.SPLIT_NUMBERS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.2/aeapi/SPLIT_NUMBERS-Function.html#GUID-729E046F-4E95-45DF-8B9F-5FBEA0C08DE5) to help:

```
delete from map_student_room
where room_id = :P1_ID
  and student_id not in (
    select column_value
    from apex_string.split_number(:P1_ASSIGNED_STUDENTS, ':')
  )
```

Then you can insert rows that are in the selection but not already in the room.

```
insert into map_student_room (
  room_id,
  student_id
)
select :P1_ID,
  column_value
from apex_string.split_number(:P1_ASSIGNED_STUDENTS, ':')
where column_value not in (
  select student_id
  from map_student_room
  where room_id = :P1_ID
)
```

I've not tested any of this code, but it should get the points across.

Another option would be to use an Interactive Grid instead of a list of values item. This is a classic master/detail scenario where students could be added and removed below the form region (typically only done after create).

Comment: It's work..
Before, i have set the default value, but i dont set used to Always, replacing any existing value in session state so the select list not re-selected..

Oh, for delete or insert, i use "apex_string.split" to get value from item..

Thank's for the solution..

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the Select2 plug-in.
Have you considered using the built-in Popup LOV, which since APEX 19.1 now allows multiple selection.